# Amazon Aurora: Does a unique field allow multiple null values?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

Ok, so my question is pretty simple, but it's one that I haven't really been able to find a solid answer to.

I am currently using a MySQL database, and I want to introduce a unique field. There will be many rows that will have a NULL value in this field, which is fine in MySQL. However, I may be transitioning to using Aurora at some stage in the future.

The Aurora description says that it's 'My-SQL compatible' and, according to the FAQ:

'Q: What does "MySQL-compatible" mean?

It means that **most** of the code, applications, drivers and tools you already use today with your MySQL databases can be used with Aurora with **little** or no change.'

This answer still leaves open the slight possibility that this feature (allowing multiple null values for a unique field) is not supported in Aurora.

Based on what I've found, my assumption is that this feature is supported, but I would like to get a concrete answer (has someone done it before etc.) if possible before I implement it in MySQL.

And if it is in fact NOT possible to have multiple NULL values for a unique field in Aurora, is there a way around it?

Regards,
Josh.

Comment: I would say it was *huge* change if it behaved differently in Aurora.

Comment: Mmmm yeah this is my thought too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I asked this question... But I actually did end up finding out the answer to it while working on a different project:

Yes, Amazon Aurora (MySQL) supports multiple null values for fields with a unique index.